# Accidentally found "and" statement in C++

Tags: c++

Today I accidentally found that "and" statement works the same way as &&

```
if( (2>1) && (3>1))
{
    cout<<"Here"<<endl;
}
```

works the same as

```
if( (2>1) and (3>1))
{
    cout<<"Here"<<endl;
}
```

So i just want to verify if this "and" statement is compatible with all versions of C++ and platforms and any more additional useful info is also helpful.

Comment: With a quick search: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and

Comment: And a whole lot more: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: Can't compile it in VS 2017.